# Can't get FancyBox to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, prettyphoto

Well at first, fancybox worked. But then when I added on to the site, it completely failed and I have no clue where I went wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>         
</script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancyImg").fancybox();
});
</script>

<div id="About-MichaelP"><p>Website made by: <a class="fancyImg" href="#MichaelP">Michael Podsiadly</a></p></div> 

<div style="display: none;">
<div id="MichaelP" class="Hide">
<h1>About Michael Podsiadly</h1>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance. And this has been getting me so tired, I can't even think straight anymore.

Comment: *sigh* please (a) shorten the snippet you've provided for us down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem (b) be a lot more specific then "completely failed"

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know. And what I meant by completely failed is that after I added the slideshow and changed the css of the web page, I tried adding the fancybox so it works when you click on the slideshow. And so I tested it and nothing happened. When it was an image, it just navigated me to that image in a new tab or a new window.

Comment: The first thing I see is that you've given your links the class `FancyImg` whereas your JS references `.fancyImg` -- pretty sure it's case sensitive. Fix that first and get back to us. **Edit:** You actually have inconsistent capitalization...

Comment: Also, the `<a href` is supposed to point to the full size version of the image. I don't know why you have it linking to `#1`. That's also inconsistent with what you've said is happening; if the JS failed it would take you to that anchor (on the same page) not to a new page.

Comment: Perhaps have another read through this http://fancybox.net/howto and try again, try to isolate the problem and use a debugger like Firebug.

Comment: This is what Firebug said: $(".fancyImg") is null
[Break On This Error] $(".fancyImg").fancybox();

Comment: Omg... This is so annoying. =/ If I only knew the problem correctly.

Comment: the only `fancyImg` class I see is in the footer, and there are no `inline` or `group` classes in your code. Also all the images have the ID of "thumber" - ID's should be unique.

Comment: Whoops. That was an error with the ID...

Comment: `$('.fancyImg')` is null? Shouldn't be null. It should be an empty list if it found nothing. You've trimmed your HTML too much now...we can't see the gallery HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey it looks like you haven't set the class of the anchor tags

```
$("a.group")
```

is referring to anchor tags with a class of "group".

Try adding the group class to your links:

```
<a href="#1" class="group">
```

OR

It could be that you're trying to include the jQuery library twice. That could cause errors.

OR

I do this one a lot: It could be that the files are in the wrong place. Is there a "js" folder? Are the files actually in there. Is the CSS file attached properly? Are the images referenced in the CSS relative to the html file or the CSS? The best way to answer these question is open up the source in Firefox and follow the links to the js and css files...

Comment: This could be wrong because I can't see what you're trying to do with so much code in the way.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is set in the correct files and the I removed one jQuery library link and left the other, one from ajax.com, but nothing happened... Everything is still the same.

Comment: What would you like the link to? jQuery Library on Ajax? If so, that this one: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js I just saw ajax and I thought it was ajax.com.

Comment: Well the website isn't up yet. I'm making it offline so it's pretty much a fail. =/

Comment: One of the files isn't included properly. Either that or you have another javascript library (like mootools) which is using the "$" and I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @Michael Run a webserver of your local machine, its great for testing and you can provide links that people can view. Google it if you don't know how.